# How to update React state once per iteration of a loop

Tags: python, reactjs, loops, state

I have built a maze solving python program, and I am trying to make a React app to visualize it. I have successfully connected the python side and the basic React side I have, and I can visualize the maze portion of the program. The issue is the agent that solves the maze will just appear over the goal instead of working its way through the maze

The maze is a grid with obstacles randomly placed on it (Pictured Here)
[Maze with Obstacles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O6sa.png)

I am trying to get the agent, which would be a blue square, to move its way through the maze one tile at a time, about every 100ms. The data the React side gets from the python side is as follows:

Python passes the initial maze matrix with the goal and the obstacles only
Python then passes an array holding each of the coordinates that the agent moves to
EX. [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]]

React displays the initial maze matrix with the obstacles and goals, but when I try to iterate through the array of coordinates for the agent, it just displays every single tile where the agent moved all at once at the end (Pictured Here)[After image with agent positions shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOCze.png) *This is a new maze generation, the obstacles are not the same as the first image*

I am aware that the React state only gets updated once, at the end of the loop. I want to find a way to make it update once per iteration, with the maze resetting to the original state at the beginning of every iteration, followed by the agent being placed. What I believe to be the relevant code is below

Start Maze Action (Occurs after user presses a button)

```
startMaze = () => {
    this.state.apiClient.startMaze().then((data) => this.moveAgent(data));
};
```

Move Agent Function (Note: There is an initial matrix and a current matrix. Current matrix is what I have holding the position of the agent with the goal and the obstacles, initial matrix just has the goal and the obstacles)

```
moveAgent = (data) => {
    data.map((coords) => {
        var newMatrix = this.state.matrix;
        newMatrix[coords[0]][coords[1]] = 2;
        this.setState({ currentMatrix: newState });
        sleep(1000);
    });
};
```

If there's anything else needed to solve the issue, just let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use `setTimeout` to fix your issue. Maybe something like this:

```
moveAgent = (data) => {
   if(data.length < 1) return;

    var coords = data.shift();
    var newMatrix = this.state.matrix;
    newMatrix[coords[0]][coords[1]] = 2;
    this.setState({ currentMatrix: newState });
    setTimeout(() => { moveAgent(data); }, 1000);
};
```

sleep does not exist in JS. So what we use here is `setTimeout` which calls a function after a given time (here 1000ms, so 1 second). And we use it to call the function again, using and removing the first element of the array each time.

Comment: Sleep is a custom function I wrote to handle the set timeout along with some other things that I felt would clutter that function. The use of data.shift() and using the setTimeout function to create a pseudo-loop bypassed the issue of React only updating the state once. Thanks a ton for the solution.